# Update data from given ID to another tables with same ID CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to make function that update client.client_status data from given $id parameters from controller end function that fetched from booking.booking_id

Here my controller

```
    function end($book_id = null) {
    if (!empty($book_id)) {
        // Booking Table
        $table = 'booking';
        $where = [
            'book_id' => $book_id,
        ];
        $data = [
            'room_status' => 1,
        ];
        $this->Model_Data->booking_update($table, $where, $data);
        
        // Client Table
        $table = 'client';
        $client_id = $???????; // How to get booking.client_id from given id parameters
        $where = [
            'client_id' => $client_id,
        ];
        $data = [
            'room_status' => 1,
        ];
        $this->Model_Data->booking_update($table, $where, $data);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('book_ended', 'Book Ended');
        redirect('book');
    }
    else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('book_end_error', 'Book End Error');
        redirect('book');
    }
}
```

Here my SQL Tables

[image]

Comment: in `booking table` is there any `client_id` column??

Comment: yes booking.book_by_client_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment in Question , `book_by_client_id` is equal to `client_id` then for :

**Accessing a single row:**

**(1) Result as an Object**

```
$data_result = $this->db->get_where('booking',array('book_id'=>$book_id ))->row();

$book_by_client_id =$data_result->book_by_client_id;

$client_id = $book_by_client_id;     // client_id
```

**(2) Result as an Array**

```
$data_result = $this->db->get_where('booking',array('book_id'=>$book_id ))->row_array();

$book_by_client_id =$data_result['book_by_client_id'];

$client_id = $book_by_client_id;     // client_id
```

**Note :** for more info about **row(); && row_array();**

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-rows